# Open m3u8 Files from iOS on PC

Tags: windows, ios, video, recording, m3u

I got an App called TV Screen on my iPhone.
There i can save TV Shows localy on my iPhone, well kind of.
I went via SSH to the Application folder and found many .ts files and a m3u8 file.

Here the m3u8 File
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/92469/5_13365986_2011-03-27.local.m3u8

Somehow i cant open that file on my windows pc. 
ideas how i can?
or how i can convert it?

Greetings, jonny

Answer (score 0):

The [.m3u8 file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) is a playlist (for m3u) in UTF-8 (for the 8). I opened it with a text editor, it just references all your .ts files:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:482475
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://192.168.1.33:62497/key.dat"
#EXTINF:11,
13012386082_11_482473_.ts
#EXTINF:11,
13012386202_11_482474_.ts
#EXTINF:10,
13012386292_10_482475_.ts
[...]
```

You can open the .ts files with VLC: http://www.videolan.org/

Comment: Hi Ludovic

I allready tried that. 
Its not possible, it allways tells me 
no suitable decoder module for fourcc `undf'.

I guess it has the correct folder only the .ts Files are crypted.

Thanks for ur help though! :)

Comment: Yes, .ts files seems to be crypted or with some drm. You can do anything about that.

Comment: But why not? I mean the iPhone app gets the dat File with the Password from the Server.
So why shouldnt my PC be able to do the same thing?

Comment: But why not? I mean the iPhone app gets the dat File with the Password from the Server.
So why shouldnt my PC be able to do the same thing? 
The URL the (not local) url shows to is
http://purchase.streamboatserver.ch/stream_decrypt.php
Just beeing curious :)